# boolean toggle in mongoose with findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I use mongoose in node js and I want to make a boolean toggle, But when I use findOneAndUpdate(As I wrote) I get "done" as false but the second time "done" is not true

finally, I want to get such logic: when I click the button, "done" should  become false if it is true and the same, when it is false it should become true

```
{
  "_id": "63be594eaceb91f14825b144",
  "tasksTitle": "Daily",
  "collectioner": "63bc41041e463e09c07db3fe",
  "collectionAuthor": "63b31ee65e03accdf60ca705",
  "tasksItems": [
    {
      "taskItemTitle": "exampleTitle",
      "deadline": 0,
      "done": true,
      "_id": "63be49f56c9c394d282b155f"
    }
  ]
}

argument "taskItemId: 63be49f56c9c394d282b155f"

tasksModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          "tasksItems._id": taskItemId,
          tasksItems: {
            $elemMatch: {
              _id: taskItemId,
            },
          },
        },
        [{ $set: { tasksItems: { done: { $eq: [false, "$done"] } } } }],
        { new: true }
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to retrieve the task and update the `taskItems` independently:

```
const task = await tasksModel.findOne({ 'tasksItems._id': taskItemId });
if (!task) return;
for (let i = 0; i < task.tasksItems.length; i++) {
  if (task.tasksItems[i]._id !== taskItemId) continue;
  task.tasksItems[i].done = !task.tasksItems[i].done;
}
await task.save();
```

Comment: I get such an error ( Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField. )

Comment: sorry for wasting your time but it also not working, now we have such error, I tried to reEdit your code but.... nothing  error: (  tasks validation failed: tasksItems.0._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"false\" (type boolean) at path \"_id\" because of \"BSONTypeError\"" )

Comment: Try to remove the `$elemMatch` condition. How do you initialize `taskItemId`?

Comment: tasksItems: [
    {
      id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      taskItemTitle: String,
      deadline: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
      },
      done: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    },
  ],

Comment: @davidTakidze My bad, I forgot to reference the `done` field in the loop

Comment: hey again, I edited "for loop", because if I want to change "done" to only a specifical object I should get only one object and  not a whole array    for (let i = 0; i < task.tasksItems.length; i++) {
        if (task.tasksItems[i]._id.toString() === taskItemId) {
          task.tasksItems[i].done = !task.tasksItems[i].done;
        }
      }

Comment: when I tried your code, I get false in every object, please edit your answer